# Error while Publishing a App from Kony Visualizer

Tags: temenos-quantum

new to Kony , trying to publish a demo app from Kony Visualizer and getting a error message, can you please help how can i debug and view logs to resolve such erorr. Appreciate all the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had that last week, restarted and tried again at a later time and it worked...

Comment: And this is Kony Visualizer! haha - but had you looked at the console logs?